# How to enable Lightning Message Channel for sandbox and production

Tags: lightning, communication

I had a hard time to have a feedback from a Visual Force Page to a Lightning web component by using iframe and postMessage.
Thus I am using Lightning Message Channel ( which is at Developer Preview stage) for my sandbox, however after creating the file of **SampleMessageChannel.messageChannel-meta.xml**, I could not deploy it to the sandbox and below is the error:
[image]

The link I used for creating this .xml file is 
[Salesforce Lightning Message channel](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/10/lightning-message-service-developer-preview.html)

Please advise if this error is due to my sandbox is not a Developer version and how to I make it becomes a Developer version to enable this feature in Sandbox and to deploy to Production using the changeset?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Winter '20 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_message_channel.htm), this is a Developer Preview and as such cannot (at the time of answering) be deployed to a Sandbox or Production org. You have to wait for it to GA before you can do that (assuming it actually goes GA in its current form).

In the short term there's actually no good way to communicate between a VF page embedded in a Lightning Page (via an iframe) and LWCs or Aura components on the page - basically because there's no API for getting Lightning URLs in Visualforce and Visualforce URLs in Lightning - and no official way to communicate between LWCs in different namespaces on the same page (this latter can be worked around using DOM Custom Events though, at least at the current time).

If you are a partner, take a look at [this posting](https://partners.salesforce.com/0D53A00004dDxgV) on the latter subject.